# Calling an endpoint with a soap payload

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I need to transform a message using WSO2 ESB and send it exactly as it has been formatted. I am receiving payload in xml format and I need to transform it into xml with soap envelope. For this I am using payload factory to transform the payload:

```
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:param="urn:www.my_url.com/param:1.6" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <soapenv:Header/>
                <soapenv:Body>
                    <param:GetUser>
                        <GetNameQue>
                            <firstname>$1</firstname>
                            <surname>$2</surname>
                        </GetNameQue>
                    </param:GetUser>
                </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//MessageGetUser/FirstName"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//MessageGetUser/Surname"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
```

Then I'm calling the other platform using:

```
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
    <call>
        <endpoint>
            <http method="post" uri-template="{uri.var.httpendpointurl}">
                <suspendOnFailure>
                    <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                    <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
                </suspendOnFailure>
                <markForSuspension>
                    <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                </markForSuspension>
            </http>
        </endpoint>
    </call>
```

I have been receiving an error for a bad formatting and after some debugging I found that my $body/ is sent and it looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <param:GetUser xmlns:param="urn:www.my_url.com/param:1.6">
      <GetNameQue xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
         <firstname>MyFirst</firstname>
         <surname>MySecond</surname>
      </GetNameQue>
   </param:GetUser>
</soapenv:Body>
```

While my $env looks exactly what it need to be send:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:param="urn:www.my_url.com/param:1.6">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <param:GetUser>
         <GetNameQue xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
         <firstname>MyFirst</firstname>
         <surname>MySecond</surname>
         </GetNameQue>
      </param:GetUser>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My question is there a way to send the envelope instead of the body or what exactly is send using a the call? For example I know that the current json ($) is the one being send when sending a json payload.

I'm sorry if my question sounds bad I just didn't find any information that helped me up to this point.
Edit: I tried following solutions but they didn't work:
[WSO2 ESB Payload Factory creates invalid SOAP envelope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160580/wso2-esb-payload-factory-creates-invalid-soap-envelope)
https://isuruuy.medium.com/how-to-construct-a-payload-with-the-soap-envelope-ce8df5032dda
https://medium.com/wso2-learning/wso2-esb-ei-apim-create-payloads-with-soap-envelope-481bc0dbf330

If you need any additional information please let me know and I will be glad to provide it.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a format to my call sends the envelope properly:

```
<call>
    <endpoint>
        <http method="post" uri-template="{uri.var.httpendpointurl}" format="soap11">
            <suspendOnFailure>
                <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
            </suspendOnFailure>
            <markForSuspension>
                <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
            </markForSuspension>
        </http>
    </endpoint>
</call>
```